# Extract data from table with condition

Tags: r, dplyr, data-wrangling

I have data. Here's an example:

```
    A tibble: 1,296 x 4
       id treatmentstart protocoltype                PDL1_date 
    <dbl> <chr>          <chr>                       <chr>     
 1   1111 05/11/2020     Chemoradiation              05/03/2020
 2  22222 03/03/2021     Chemo plus PD-1 plus CTLA-4 01/03/2020
 3 333333 08/04/2018     Anti-VEGF plus Chemo        NA        
 4 444444 07/06/2019     Chemoradiation              03/08/2018
 5 555555 09/12/2020     Chemo plus PDl-1            07/11/2020
 6 666666 05/06/2018     PD-1                        08/02/2017
 7 666666 07/07/2018     Chemotherapy                08/02/2017
 8 777777 07/05/2019     Chemotherapy                06/03/2020
 9 999999 08/08/2018     Chemoradiation              08/05/2020
10 999999 12/07/2017     PDL-1                       08/05/2020
```

As you can see, some of the IDs are repeated, but have different treatments (type of protocol)
I need to extract the IDs that meet the following conditions:
Test date, earlier treatment start date, and treatment type all that include "PD1" or "PDL1", if the ID has multiple treatments then I need to compare treatment dates and choose the earliest treatment date and compare with the test date, if the test earlier then it fits, if not then not.
In conclusion: only those who have a test date before a certain type of treatment ("PD1" or "PDL1") and have not received any other treatment before the test date should be selected. Here is an example of what should come up:

```
A tibble: 1,296 x 4
       id treatmentstart protocoltype                PDL1_date 
    <dbl> <chr>          <chr>                       <chr>     
 1  22222 03/03/2021     Chemo plus PD-1 plus CTLA-4 01/03/2020
 2 555555 09/12/2020     Chemo plus PDl-1            07/11/2020
 6 666666 05/06/2018     PD-1                        08/02/2017
```

So 1111,44444,77777 excluded by treatment condition(not received any PD1/PDL1), 333333 no PDL1_date, 99999 received PD-1 and it's before PDL1date, but received other treatment before PDL1date.

I have tried dplyr filter (PDL1_date<treatmentstart), but I am stuck on comparing ID with same ID.
Please help.

Comment: If you could share a reproducible piece of your data, we could help you much more efficient.

Comment: You can use `dput` function to create a reproducible example of your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to share a reproducible data to help you, but maybe this could help you:

```
data %>% 
      filter(grepl("PD-1|PD[Ll]-1",protocoltype)) %>%
      group_by(id) %>%
      filter(treatmentstart == min(treatmentstart)) %>% ungroup()
```

Comment: Thank you for helping. I think that a solution:     ```data %>%
    group_by(id) %>%
    filter(treatmentstart == min(treatmentstart)) %>% ungroup() %>%
    filter(PDL1_date <= treatmentstart) %>%
    filter(grepl("PD-1|PD[Ll]-1",protocoltype))```